# Prevent direct access to all files and folders mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to prevent direct access via browser for any one . Searched internet and found this piece of code and added in webconfig

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

But after adding this , what happens is that even my application is unable to access any javascript and css and images and due to which my login page is looking like a garbage .

What should be the workaround ?

Comment: You can't, that's not how HTTP works. Users need to be able to download your assets (.js, .css, .jpg, ...) in order to view your site.

Comment: Setup authorization rules for the sub-directories. (e.g. `<location path="Scripts" allowOverride="False"><authorization><allow users="*" /></authorization></location>`)

Answer (score 0):

The default rules in an MVC project are fairly well set up to prevent access to any sensitive files (e.g. code - .cs, .cshtml, .config), while still allowing access to static content in the Content and Scripts folders.

If you're trying to block additional static content, then you should put that in a location just for protected static content and set a rule on that folder only.

If there's something else you're looking to block, you should explain why in your question.